# RPM database corrupt

Tags: database, rpm

Sometime ago I managed to erase the /var/lib/rpm folder which basically contains information about all the rpms in the System

The problem posed is that I cannot query nor Upgrade using the yum

I did the steps mentioned like rpm --rebuild and ll that but it did not help

Its my pure curiosity to know of a method by which we can restore the database of the installed rpm's

I say curiosity, because the server runs fine without it also !!!

Hope no one does this anytime ... I lost many days sleep for this

Thanks in advance for reading this post and thinking of a solution

Regards

amRit

Answer (score 4):

Your only chance, if this system is important enough, is to reinstall only to db:

```
rpm -Uvh --justdb <package>
```

You could use your /root/install.log and /var/log/yum.log to get a list of installed RPMs, or, if you have a similar system you could get the RPM list from there.

That said, if this system can suffer downtime, I'd suggest re-installing as the best way. Otherwise, see the comment above.

Best of luck

Comment: On RHEL/Fedora/Centos there should also be /var/log/rpmpkgs created by a cronjob, you can use this as a manifest file to RPM but you still need to download all the files into a directory and do the justdb install with the manifest file rather than <package>

Answer (score 2):

Edit:  I read wrong -- if you removed the entire /var/lib/rpm directory you are a bit hosed.

You said you already did this first step, but for future reference (and for anyone else that runs into this)

delete `/var/lib/rpm/__db.*`

then

`rpmdb –rebuilddb`

It's not really a big deal, your system isn't hosed.  Just run the above command(s) and you should be back in business.

Answer (score 1):

If you've kept a backup, then you might be able to restore it. Otherwise, you've wiped the only copy of the RPM database. (The `rpm --rebuilddb` command rebuilds some files in that directory from others.) Your system is basically hosed.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to, but you can try to set up a new empty RPM database (copy from fresh install?) and reinstall all currently installed packages in the current installed versions. You may have a look into your rpm (or maybe yum, if you're using it) logs to determine currently installed packages.